# github: How would you delete all commits by a certain username

Tags: git, github

When I first started out with this repo, I hadn't used git before and biffed the setup by mistyping my email or something so all commits for a while were made by the user "unknown." I found an answer on here to convert all the "unknown" commits to my name but what it actually did was duplicate the commit and apply my name. So now I have all these "unknown" user commits scattered.

So I was wondering about some commands to run to delete all commits by "unknown" user.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will have to make use of `git filter-branch` in your repo and force push it to Github.

Here's an example from the official docs that deals almost with the same situation where you want to remove commits by a particular user:

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "Darl McBribe" ];
    then
            skip_commit "$@";
    else
            git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' HEAD
```

Note that this will rewrite your history and it might affect others who also use your repo. Some advice from Github:

> Dealing with collaborators
>
> You may have collaborators that pulled your tainted branch and created
> their own branches off of it. After they fetch your new branch, they
> will need to use git rebase on their own branches to  rebase them on
> top of the new one. The collab should also ensure that their branch
> doesn’t reintroduce the file, as this will override the .gitignore
> file. Make sure your collab uses rebase  and not merge, otherwise he
> will just reintroduce the file and the entire tainted history… and
> likely encounter some merge conflicts.

http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/

Comment: I know this is old, but the function `skip_commit` is missing. It's in the official docs https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_examples