# How to delete specific user commits in github

Tags: git, svn, version-control, github

I am `JS` developer,I created a public `Repo` for my Application.Both `js` and `html` guys made commits and pushed to `Repo`NOW I want to delete `JS` developers commits not only commits wants to delete their code completely from `Repo`.Just I want to show `html` guys commits and their code itself.

I know the `JS` developers userNames.So I have to delete commits based on `userNames`.

can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [github: How would you delete all commits by a certain username](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058509/github-how-would-you-delete-all-commits-by-a-certain-username)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about removing commits based on Author, but if you have the list of SHA ids of commits, you can run the following command for each SHA:

```
git rebase -p --onto SHA^ SHA
```