# Git pushing as 2 authors

Tags: git

I was just looking at the git commit log, and apparantly I have been pushing as 2 authors. So I have duplicates.

How can I delete the history of all the commits? I spent a good hour finding information to do so, but I can't do `git push --force` (It gets rejected, non-fast-forward)

The `git log`:

http://pastie.org/private/fwxzqoin5lhmhwzsxdnnga

Comment: Would it be possible to see a snippet of your git log?

Comment: @AshutoshJindal done.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058509/github-how-would-you-delete-all-commits-by-a-certain-username). You can delete commit for specific author.

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates? You may be pushing as two authors from different machines, but Git will take care of "duplicates" (depending on what you mean).

Comment: @deepakb - that uses `git push --force`, which I cannot use.

Comment: @EricPlaton, I am using one machine. Please have a look at the `git log`.

Comment: Do you really want to delete history? Locally and on the remote? Or just reverting the changes are enough? Note that after pushing, modifying history is harder and sometimes even more in a really shared and active remote.

Comment: @EricPlaton, yes I do want to delete the history, locally and on the remote. Having duplicate commits is very confusing.

Comment: Two machines/accounts were just setting examples. The other points are more important to give meaningful answer...

Comment: @EricPlaton OK. Is it possible to remove the history without being able to `git push --force`? And if so, how?

Comment: @KevinS Sorry for my silence. Yes, it is possible, but hairy, hard, and discouraged by the documentation. Having said so, I will answer with a few ideas, that may or may not work depending on your details (my questions are still pending---perhaps unfortunate rebase commands?)

Comment: I believe the title of your post is misleading. The two authors are not the real problem to solve. You rather target rewriting history, and there are already quite some questions about it on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete commits but you can do `git reset --hard <hash>` to your starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following command, but beware of the consequences (Git v2.6.4):

```
git checkout <ref you want to keep from>
git checkout -b my_new_master
git push origin +my_new_master:master
```

The Git garbage collector should then destroy all commits from the old master. [From the docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> git push origin +dev:master
>
> Update the origin repository's master branch with the dev branch, allowing non-fast-forward updates.  This can leave unreferenced commits dangling in the origin repository.  Consider the following situation, where a fast-forward is not possible:
>
> ```
>                        o---o---o---A---B  origin/master
>                                 \
>                                  X---Y---Z  dev
> ```
>
> The above command would change the origin repository to
>
> ```
>                                  A---B  (unnamed branch)
>                                 /
>                        o---o---o---X---Y---Z  master
> ```
>
> Commits A and B would no longer belong to a branch with a symbolic name, and so would be unreachable. As such, these commits would be removed by a git gc command on the origin repository.

Alternatively, it is possible to get the same result breaking down the steps, notably for older versions of Git. I have done it on some dummy repository, but it is quite long, and I believe pointless, as it is discouraged for very good reasons: Doing this you break *others* repositories. But the above command should be good enough is your are working with a personal or low-change repository.